# How to call function inside custom attribute class

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

Lets say i have the following attribute class.

```
 //Attribute Implementation 
    public abstract class TestAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public abstract void UpdateSomething(string s);
    }


    public class CustomAttTest : TestAttribute
    {
        private State state;

        public CustomAttTest(State state)
        {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public override void UpdateSomething(string s)
        {
            if (state.Equals(State.First))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First State!! " + s);
            }
        }
    }

    public enum State
    {
        First, Second, Third
    }
```

How can i call the Updatesomthing function inside the attribute class?
following is the attribute implementation example.

```
    public abstract class Vehicle
    {
        //Coode
    }

    [CustomAttTest(State.First)]
    public class Ferrari : Vehicle
    {
        //Code
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Ferrari();
            //How do i call the UpdateSomething implemented insde the CustomAttTest attribute class?
        }
    }

    public abstract class Vehicle
    {
        //Coode
    }

    [CustomAttTest(State.First)]
    public class Ferrari : Vehicle
    {
        //Code
    }

    //Attribute Implementation 
    public abstract class TestAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public abstract void UpdateSomething(string s);
    }


    public class CustomAttTest : TestAttribute
    {
        private State state;

        public CustomAttTest(State state)
        {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public override void UpdateSomething(string s)
        {
            if (state.Equals(State.First))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First State!! " + s);
            }
        }
    }

    public enum State
    {
        First, Second, Third
    }


}
```

Comment: Trust me i did a lot of goggling before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection:

```
foo.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<CustomAttTest>().UpdateSomething(...);
```

However, you should probably use an abstract method or property instead of an attribute.

Comment: Hey do you think, it would be good practice to add the abstract method inside Vehicle class and override in Ferrari?

Comment: Also, is there a way to execute the Updatesomthing() function when there are multiple attributed attributes from customerAttTest?

Comment: @RajuKumar#2: `GetCustomAttributes<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.